# Retreive the current record id in IsBefore context on IsInsert

Tags: triggercontext, before-trigger

Can we get the current record Id on IsBefore context on IsInsert trigger? I'm trying to create a Child record to a Parent record on its IsBefore context when its inserting? Is that possible? Or else do it need to stick with IsAfter Context?

Thanks,
Lahiru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current record id is only available in After inert trigger you can't get that in before insert trigger.

Comment: Thanks Himanshu. I was under impression that since we can run through Trigger.New on Trigger.IsBefore context, we might be able to retrieve the Id on the context. 
I'll stick with the IsAfter